# server can't find :NXDOMAIN -- Ubuntu 18

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, dns-hosting, powerdns

Went thru all possible available solutions over the internet, before posting the question here.

I'm trying to replicate my working DNS production server onto a staging environment using the same Ansible Playbooks (with new values of-course :))

Only difference between the 2 environments are, domain names are different.

**Production (working):**

```
pdns_zones_create:
  - aero.amadeus.com.

pdns_hosts_create:
  - name: aus.aero.amadeus.com.
    zone: aero.amadeus.com
    type: A
    content: <IP>
```

**Staging:**

```
pdns_zones_create:
  - solutions.amadeus.com.

pdns_hosts_create:
  - name: eng.solutions.amadeus.com.
    zone: solutions.amadeus.com
    type: A
    content: <IP>
```

It's a PowerDNS on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

```
/etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 170.10.18.83
search amadeus.com
```

No additional configurations like named.conf etc.. What am I doing wrong ?

`dig +short NS aero.amadeus.com` leads to

```
as-prod-145.amadeus.com.
as-prod-146.amadeus.com.
```

while, `dig +short NS solutions.amadeus.com` in Staging env, does not return an output.

Comment: Crossposted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573819/server-cant-find-nxdomain-ubuntu-18

Comment: When debugging DNS related problems you first need to check authoritative nameservers. For that you need to use dig `@` option

Comment: @PatrickMevzek : I realized that I've to ask such questions in the serverFault. Deleted the post there.

Comment: `dig eng.solutions.amadeus.com @10.44.15.78`
gives the A record for the eng.solutions.amadeus.com

Comment: @dev but your nameserver is set to another address `nameserver 170.10.18.83`.  The error message means that the queried domain couldn't be found.